# do you need destructor to destroy global int, float or std::string variables?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, int, destructor

I know that destructor is used to destroy global pointers in a class but do i need them to destroy normal variables like int or std::string?

how about array like int num[2]?

what variable types should be destroyed in destructor?

for example:

```
class myclass
{
public:
   myclass()
   ~myclass()
   {
      delete num;
      delete ar_num;
      delete str;
   }
private:
   int num;
   std::string str;
   int ar_num[2] = {0,1}; 
}
```

Comment: You need to read up on the basics of C++. If you already have, find another source because the one you are currently using is not very good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should only `delete` what you `new`. Since you don't allocate the member variables yourself, you should not (and as none of the variables are pointers, you can't) free them with `delete`.

Rule of thumb: If you do `new` then you need to do `delete`.

Comment: What's interesting is that his code shows something unrelated to his question.  It's as if he's conflating `delete` and destruction: his destructor certainly will destruct `str`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Everything should be destructed in the destructor, but...

All direct members will be destructed automatically; you cannot
have a destructor which doesn't destruct them.  (In some cases,
like `int`, the "destructor" is in fact a no-op.)

You're confusing destruction and deletion.  You only `delete`
things which have been dynamically allocated.  (Directy—if
you do `new MyClass`, `num` will be dynamically allocated as
part of `MyClass`.  But you shouldn't, and indeed you cannot
delete it.) The argument of `delete` must be a pointer, and it
must point to something that was created using `new`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some variables which are assigned memory on process stack. So, as soon the process exits, the stack will automatically clean the memory occupied. You only need to `delete` the variables for whom you have allocated memory by `new`.

You can see this as the `malloc`ing in `C`. You only need to `free` the memory dynamically allocated on your request.